# Please help with translation of inscription on a bone (?) tablet and purpose. Thank you

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification

[image]
Chinese characters

[image]
Man riding on a Bull

Answer (score 1):

麒麟送子 (Kirin gifts son)

麒麟 (Kirin) is the divine beast in the second picture

It is a good luck charm for bringing a son to the family

*The divine beast bestows a son on you, and this son must be favored by heaven*

*觀世音菩薩 (Guanyin Bodhisattva) rides the 麒麟*